# multiple child item selection from the 3rd drop down list of depedent list ( from dynamic multiple rows )

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have dynamic generated rows for new entries in my script and in that dynamic generated row I am using three dependent drop down list country, State and City respectively. This script working fine as per my requirements. Currently single item can be selected from the dependent  list. But Now I wanted that after selection from first (country) and (State) list, I want to select multiple cities value from 3rd list
here is my current code :

```
                   `<table class="table table-bordered">
                 <thead class="table-success" style="background-color: #3fbbc0;">
                   <tr>
            <th width="15%"><center>Type</th> 
            <th width="15%"><center>Service</th> 
            <th width="15%"><center>Machine</th>                   
            <th width="5%"><center>Qty</th>                       
            <th width="10%"><center>Rate</th>
            <th width="5%"></th>                                               
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" onclick="BtnAdd()">Add             Item</button>                          
                      </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                       <tbody id="TBody">
        <tr id="TRow" class="d-none">
        
            <td>
                <Select  class="country form-control text-end" name="country[]" id = "country" >
                    <option value=""> Select Type</option>
                    <?php
                    include('db1.php');
                    $query = "select * from country";
                    // $query = mysqli_query($con, $qr);
                    $result = $con->query($query);
                    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>'."\r";
                        }
                    }     
                    ?>    
                </select> 
            </td>
            
            <td>
                <Select class="state form-control text-end" name="state[]" id = "state">
                    <option value="">select Service</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            
            <td>
                <Select  class="city form-control text-end" name="city[]" id = "city">
                    <option value="">Select Machine</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            
            <td><input type="text" class="qty form-control text-end" name="qty[]" id="ccc" value="" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="price form-control text-end" name="price1[]" id="ddd" value="" /></td>
            
            <td class="NoPrint"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success"  style="line-height: 1;" onclick="BtnDel(this)">x</button></td>
        
        </tr>   
    </tbody> 
</table>    
     
            
<script>

$(document).ready(function () { 

    $(document).on("change", ".country", function(){    

      // Get the current row element
      let row = $(this).closest("tr");
      // Get the country id from the current select element
      let country_id = $(this).val();
      // Use AJAX to send a request to the server-side script
      $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "response.php",
        data: {
          id: country_id
        },
        datatype: "html",
        success: function(data) {
          // Find the state select element in the same row and update its options
          row.find(".state").html(data);
          // Find the city select element in the same row and clear its options
          row.find(".city").html('<option value="">Select Machine</option>');               
            row.find('.qty').val('');
            row.find('.price').val('');
        }
      });       
    });


    // When the user changes the value of the state select element
    $(document).on("change", ".state", function(){
      // Get the current row element
      let row = $(this).closest("tr");
      // Get the state id from the current select element
      let state_id = $(this).val();
      // Use AJAX to send a request to the server-side script
      $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "response.php",
        data: {
          sid: state_id
        },
        datatype: "html",
        success: function(data) {
          // Find the city select element in the same row and update its options
          row.find(".city").html(data);                 
            row.find('.qty').val('');
            row.find('.price').val('');
        }
      });           
    }); 
         

    $(document).on("change", ".city", function(){                                                                            
      // Get the current row element
      let row = $(this).closest("tr");
      // Get the state id from the current select element
      let city_id = $(this).val();
        
        
      if (city_id.length == 0) {    
            row.find('.qty').val('');
            row.find('.price').val(''); 
        //return;
      } else {       
            
        // Use AJAX to send a request to the server-side script
            $.ajax({
          url: 'response.php',
          type: 'POST', 
                dataType: 'JSON',
          data: {cid: city_id} ,
                
          success: function(response) {
                    row.find('.qty').val(response.qty);
                    row.find('.price').val(response.price);
            }
        }); 
      }
                
    });
    
});
</script>`
```

and here is response .php file

```
          `<?php
include_once 'db1.php';
if (!empty($_POST["id"])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $query = "SELECT id, state FROM state WHERE country_id=$id";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo '<option value="">Select Service</option>';
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['state'] . '</option>';
        }
    }
}

if (!empty($_POST['sid'])) {
    $id = $_POST['sid'];
    $query1 = "SELECT id, city FROM city WHERE state_id=$id";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($con, $query1);
    if ($result1->num_rows > 0) {
        echo '<option value="">Select Machine</option>';
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
            echo '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['city'] . '</option>';
        }
    }
}

if(!empty($_POST['cid'])){
    $city_id = $_POST['cid'];
    $query_asset = "SELECT qty, price FROM assets WHERE city_id=$city_id";
    $result_asset = mysqli_query($con, $query_asset);
    if ($result_asset->num_rows > 0) {
            $row_asset = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_asset);
            $response = array('qty' => $row_asset['qty'], 'price' => $row_asset['price']);  
        }
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}`
?>~~~
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the `multiple` attribute to the City select?

Comment: Definitely,  it change the shape of city list and secondly its stop showing value in qty and rate field

Comment: If you want to allow multiple values, you have to use the multiple attribute. Is the shape really important? Regardless, you can probably fix that with some CSS. Have you debugged the qty and rate fields? You seem to be expecting one city id in your ajax call currently, but need to account for multiple city ids.

Comment: u r right, i think its not work able, as qty and rate value will create issue in it

Answer (score 1):

Use the multiple attribute in the select of the third city list and change

> ```
> <select class="city form-control text-end" name="city[]" id="city" multiple>
> ```

and in $(document).on("change", ".state", function() changes the line:

```
 success: function (data) {
            row.find(".city").html(data);
            row.find(".city").prop("disabled", false); // Enable the multi-select
            row.find('.qty').val('');
            row.find('.price').val('');
        }
```

Comment: ok but what about values in qty and price column ????????

Comment: In this case, you will have to change the logic when it changes the city and save it in an array of selected cities and then make an AJAX request to obtain the quantities and prices for the selected cities, updating the corresponding quantities and prices in the appropriate fields